# GCP / Google Workspace Add-On JavaScript Origin

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-api-js-client

I have a Google Apps Script Add-On that will not authenticate any more. It throws the following error:

> Not a valid origin for the client:
> https://n-kn26x****-script.googleusercontent.com
> has not been whitelisted for client ID
> 1061****.apps.googleusercontent.com.
> Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this
> origin for your project's client ID.

If I check the `window.location.orgin` in the console, I get exactly that `*.googleusercontent.com` url.

Now whitelisting this url no longer works (it used to), it throws the following error:

> The request failed because one of the field of the resource is invalid.
> Tracking number: c50***

The function that throws the error is the following and is run from the sidebar a Google Sheet:

```js
function initClient()  {
        console.log('INIT');
        return new Promise(resolve =>{
        gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: API_KEY,
            discoveryDocs: [],
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
        }).then(function ()  {
            // Listen for sign-in state changes.
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
            // Handle the initial sign-in state.
            updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                resolve(isAuthenticated);
            }).catch(
            e => {
                makeModal('OAUTH2', $.t('gapiLoadPb'), false);
                console.log('OAuth2 GAPI Error: ' + e.details);
                google.script.run.consoleOauth2Pb(e);
            });
        })
    }
```

I've searched around a lot, most of the tips are around changing the project, creating new credetials, etc. I've tried all that.

I would really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: [mcve].........

Comment: good point, did that

Comment: This is a bug and it's reported. See duplicate answer linked above. Any workarounds/answers  should be directed to the original thread